# Trying to Store record in excel file in Spring

Tags: java

"Request" tab in excel file is input from the user.

if rows is 3 . user input 3 values like 5 2 4. when  click on print it only print first value in all columns instead of printing 5 2 4 respectively.

Text box in JSP

```
<input type="text" name="request" placeholder="request"/>
```

here the code is

```
int count = 1;

for (SpecialOrder invoice : invoiceList) {

  Row row = sheet.createRow(count++);
  row.createCell(0).setCellValue(invoice.getPartnumber());
  row.createCell(1).setCellValue(invoice.getInterchangeno());
  row.createCell(2).setCellValue(invoice.getPartdescription());
  row.createCell(3).setCellValue(invoice.getLocation());
  row.createCell(4).setCellValue(invoice.getMakemodelcode());
  row.createCell(5).setCellValue(invoice.getQuantity());
  row.createCell(6).setCellValue(invoice.getInvoicenumber());
  row.createCell(7).setCellValue(invoice.getMpstock());
  row.createCell(8).setCellValue(request.getParameter("request"));

}
```

[image: excel result]

Comment: You want the value in the Request field to be counted down like 5>4>3? This is very unclear.

Comment: you have never decremented count of count2. hence everytime it sets value which it got from request(e.g. 5)

Comment: No. I don't want decrement. value can be any number like 8, 4 , 6 . These values are input by user. I Just want to get all the values in all columns. For now its just printing only first value in all columns.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your post, you're iterating over a collection of `SpecialOrder` objects and setting the value of cell 8 to the value of `request.getParameter("request")`, which is always going to return the same value for each iteration of the loop. How about calling a getter on your invoice object  (ie - `invoice.getRequest()`) like you do for all the other cell values that *are* returning different values as desired?